# Confused about type conversion in C++

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

In C++, the following lines have me confused:

```
int temp = (int)(0×00);

int temp = (0×00int);
```

What is the difference between those 2 lines?

Comment: Where did you get that code from?

Comment: why on earth had you got this doubt?`int temp = (0×00int);`- why????

Comment: another thing that I learnt today. Whilst technically you can use "(int)" to type cast, the C++ way would be to write "static_cast<int>"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are invalid because you are using `×` instead of `x`:

```
test.cpp:6: error: stray '\215' in program
test.cpp:6: error: expected primary-expression before "int"
test.cpp:6: error: expected `)' before "int"
```

But even fixing that, the second still isn't valid C++ because you can't write `0x00int`:

```
test.cpp:6:13: invalid suffix "int" on integer constant
```

The first is valid (after changing `×` to `x`) and assigns the value 0 to temp. The cast is unnecessary here though - you don't need a cast just because the constant is written in hexadecimal. You can just write:

```
int temp = 0x00;
```

Comment: To clarify a bit more, the second statement tells the compiler that you want to assign "temp" some value. Using the "0x" prefix tells it that this value is going to be expressed in HexaDecimal. Valid characters for hexadecimal number are: 1234567890abcdef. Now you must see the problem in your statement.

Answer (score 3):

Ways to cast:

```
int temp = (int)0x00;  // Standard C-style cast
int temp = int(0x00);  // Function-style cast
int temp = static_cast<int>(0x00);  // C++ style cast, which is clearer and safer
int temp = reinterpret_cast<int>("Zero"); // Big-red-flag style unsafe cast
```

The fun thing about static_cast and reinterpret_cast is that a good compiler will warn you when you're using them wrong, at least in some scenarios.

Visual Studio 2005 for example will throw an error if you try to reinterpret_cast 0x00 to an int, because that conversion is available in a safe way.  The actual message is: "Conversion is a valid standard conversion, which can be performed implicitly or by use of static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast".

Answer (score 1):

The first will assign `0` to `temp`

Second will result in compilation error.

When the scanner sees `0×` it expects it to be followed with hexadecimal digit(s), but when it sees `i` which is not a valid hex digit it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

The first one takes the hex value 0x00 as an int, and uses it to initialize the variable temp.

The second one is a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

First line is a valid C++, which basically equate to

```
int temp = 0;
```

while the second one will fail to compile (as suggested by everyone here).